# Set theory notation, commas

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A = \{\{b^2+2k: k\in\mathbb Z\}: b\in\mathbb N, b < 3\}\cap M$$
Is that correct? I'm trying to say that the set $A$ is equal to the intersection of set $M$ and the set of all numbers which are of the form $b^2+2k$ where $k$ is any integer and $b$ is any positive integer which is greater than $3$. If not how would I write this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in that. Try (and yes, comma instead of $\land$ is not uncommon)
$$A=\{b^2+2k: k\in\mathbb Z, b\in\mathbb N, b>3\}\cap M $$

Comment: Thank you very much, and if instead k ∈ N too, could I write A={b2+2k:k,b∈N,b>3}∩M or would I have to write A={b2+2k:k∈N,b∈N,b>3}∩M

Comment: @John Both notations are correct, the first one being a little more elegant (because it's easier to read "k and b natural numbers" instead of "k natural number and b natural number")